# Manually triggering change event doesn't work

Tags: jquery

There is a text element with change event attached through `$('input.filename').bind('change', function(){...})`, and there is a popup which triggers this event by `$('input.filename').trigger('onchange')|.change()`.

Exception: if change event attached through "onchange" attribute triggering works!

Attaching code looks:

```
input.change(function () {
        var dims = {
            'width': settings.previewWidth,
            'height': settings.previewHeight
        };
        updateImagePreview(input, preview, dims);
    });
```

Triggering code looks like this:

```
var input = $("input[name='any_name']", window.opener.document);
    input
        .val("<?=$choice ?>")
        .trigger("onchange");
    window.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand completely the context but the correct event to trigger is `change` and not `onchange` with jquery.

```
input.trigger('change'); // not "onchange"
```

or

```
input.change();
```

Comment: The complete context is not very clear. Is the triggering code called from the popup or the parent window ? Is the value correctly set before the trigger should happen ?

Comment: Exactly from the popup window. About value good guess :). I'll try it.

Comment: ARe you sure the `input` contains the element ? Be aware that jquery always returns something so you get no error when using the object, nothing simply happens.

Comment: Yes I'm sure and I even debugged it and there was a proper input element, but still nothing triggered

Comment: Set up a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) because as is it is impossible to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply do [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) or trigger("change"):

```
var input = $("input[name='any_name']", window.opener.document);
    input
        .val("<?=$choice ?>")
        .trigger("change");
```

or more simply

```
var input = $("input[name='any_name']", window.opener.document);
    input
        .val("<?=$choice ?>")
        .change();
```

If you use jQuery <1.4 the event will not bubble up in Internet Explorer

Comment: Maybe the matter is in place of triggering, cause i trigger it from popup and it works when callback entered in attribute 'onchange'.

Comment: @setty are you sure that `var input = $("input[name='any_name']", window.opener.document)` returns something? have you tried doing `alert(input.length);` after it?

Comment: Thanx guys for answers but it seems like a security constraint, because it works only if element has attribute and i can't find any solution, maybe browser somehow blocks triggering event attached in such way. I will fins another way to implement my widget